# FastReport 4 VCL, Summary of each unique detail row on last page

Tags: delphi, fastreport

First there is a normal master-detail report, but in the end on a new page I want to summary fields on M and then a summary the values for each detail row.
(There is multiple fields to be summarized for both M and D).

```
**M1: 100**
D1: 11
D2: 12
D3: 13

**M2: 110**
D1: 21
D2: 22

**M3: 120**
D1: 31
D2: 32

<page2>
ReportSummary = H <summary of all M = 330 (100+110+120)>
<??Band??>
D1 <summary of all D1 = 11+21+31>
D2 <summary of all D2 = 12+22+32>
D3 <summary of all D3 = 13>
```

I have found that creating a second page and using a ReportSummary I can solve the last Master summary part.
But how can I get the last page Detail/Row summary for each unique detail?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you put a second MasterData connected to your Dataset on that second page, and GroupBands to summarize items.

Basically you would do a second loop on your data, just to summarize data instead of listing it.

PS: Your report can have as many MasterData bands as Datasets you want to report, and reporting two times the same dataset shouldn't be a problem either.